# О странностях русского языка

Tags: орфография, приложение, раздельно-дефис

Есть правило, что существительные, которые образованы сложением двух самостоятельных слов без соединительной гласной пишутся через дефис.
Есть другое правило, которое гласит, что такие существительные пишутся раздельно, если одно из них обозначает родовое понятие, а другое – видовое.

---

Как тогда объяснить эти случаи?

> Суп харчо, суп-пюре / ресторан бистро, ресторан-кабаре / шкаф-купе.

---

Где тут логика?

Comment: Cуп-пюре — это вид супа, а харчо — название. "Харчо" можно употребить без "суп", в отличие от "пюре".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Действительно, иногда сложно понять логику написания некоторых составных слов и сочетаний с разными приставками и приложениями, так как в этой теме существует много исключений, а язык постоянно пополняется новыми заимствованиями. В сомнительных случаях нужно обращаться к словарям, хотя они могут противоречить друг другу, отставать от практики письма и тенденций.

> 4. П р а в и л о. **Сочетания с постпозитивным неизменяемым определением, выраженным существительным или прилагательным, пишутся раздельно**, напр.: *платье мини, юбка макси, кофе глясе, конфеты ассорти, витамины драже, котлеты де-воляй, куры гриль, овощи гриль, **суп харчо**, стиль либерти, бумага верже, нитки мулине, купальник бикини, шляпа сомбреро, цирк шапито, **ресторан бистро**, дети индиго, стиль кантри, шоу латино, язык хинди, время пик, час икс, идея фикс.*
>
> И с к л ю ч е н и я. Пишутся через **дефис** некоторые сочетания с постпозитивным неизменяемым определением: бас-буфф, бас-профундо, девушка-кокни, жилетка-болеро, задача-максимум, задача-минимум, крем-фреш, креп-гофре (хотя юбка гофре), кросс-кантри, лётчик-камикадзе, опера-буфф, программа-максимум, программа-минимум, **ресторан-кабаре**, **суп-пюре**, театр-буфф, театр-варьете, театр-кабаре, **шкаф-купе**.

Источник: [Орфографическое комментирование русского словаря](https://oross.ruslang.ru/paragraph/46#rule4).

Что касается предложенных для обсуждения слов и сочетаний (они выделены мною в цитате), то их написание, по всей видимости, соответствует тому, о чём говорится в вопросе.

Слова ***харчо*** и ***бистро*** по отношению к словам ***суп*** и ***ресторан*** – частные (видовые) понятия, а ***пюре, кабаре, купе*** – равноправные.

Comment: Значит, эти исключения можно только заучить?

Comment: А почему шкаф-купе не вид шкафа?

Comment: @Ajgy  Можно заучить, можно писать от чувства языка, от знания похожих случаев. // Шкаф-купе – это вид шкафа, но слово "купе" не вид шкафа, а самостоятельное, полноправное слово, то есть не зависимое от слова "шкаф". Предположим, есть такой шкаф – *бомбо*, вот тогда бы писали "шкаф бомбо".

Comment: Не могу уловить разницы. Почему не написать тогда "шкаф-бомбо"?

Comment: @Ajgy Потому что бомбо – это только шкаф, его вид, а купе – нет. Вот я и говорю, что нужно сверяться со словарями, если есть сомнения. А почему не написать так – вопрос к умам, которые анализируют, исследуют лингвистические хитросплетения и выводят свои правила для широкого пользования.

Comment: Хорошо.Это если шкаф. А если посмотреть выше. "Витамины драже", ведь "драже"  - это не только витамины, но и конфеты. Тогда как тут?

Comment: @Ajgy Вопрос был об определенных словах, я написал своё мнение, и, конечно же, внимательно посмотрел на все примеры из источника (кстати, на мой взгляд, очень хороший, его постоянно рекомендует Грамота.ру в своих ответах на аналогичные вопросы). И *драже*, да, тоже поначалу засомневался, почему так, но посмотрел (да хотя бы в Википедии) и понял, что это всё-таки вид лекарственной формы, который перекочевал и к конфетам. // Тема сложная, согласен, короче, смотрим словари.

Comment: "Своё название конфеты в виде драже получили благодаря французскому слову dragée, которое обозначает одну из форм выпуска лекарственных препаратов".

Comment: Да, но получается, что аргумент с одним единственным экземпляром не подходит, Нужно только смотреть в словарь?

Comment: @Ajgy Не понял, с каким экземпляром? Исключения есть везде, но закономерности всё же тоже можно уловить. Спасибо за вопрос и принятие ответа!

Comment: Ну бомбо - это лишь шкаф. Глясе - это лишь кофе. С драже так не получается.

Comment: @Ajgy Нет, думаю, что всё нормально с драже. Это определенная форма чего-то мелкого, и неважно чего. Если отдельно сказать "драже", то нужно понимать к чему оно относится, что конкретизирует. Так же как и в сочетаниях "платье мини", "юбка макси" – мини, макси не являются самостоятельными без родового слова и могут относиться к любым предметам.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140199/discussion-between-ajgy-and--).