# Суп-харчо / суп харчо

Tags: орфография, дефис, раздельно-дефис, приложения

Можете сказать, как правильно? Я уверен, что 1-й вариант правильный, но одна персона говорит, что всё наоборот, поэтому я у вас, совы, решил проконсультироваться.

1. Суп харчо.
2. Суп-харчо.

В книгах, оказывается, чёрт-те что: [Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%87%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF-%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%87%D0%BE&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: харчо не бывает пилы, автомобиля, тренажера. Харчо - это суп, суп харчо - не нужно дефиса.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Грамота.ру**](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=287296)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[**суп харчо**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BF%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%87%D0%BE&all=x)

См. также ответ на [аналогичный вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472534/%D0%9E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%85-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0).