# О шапке-ушанке и шапке-невидимке

Tags: приложение, раздельно-дефис

Почему ставится дефис между словами в **шапке-ушанке**, если отношения родо-видовые? Род — шапки, вид — ушанка. Слово **ушанка** всегда называет шапку.
Это не тот же случай, что **шапка-невидимка**: невидимкой называется не только шапка.

Растолкуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Классный зимний вопрос, Татьяна Алексеевна! Мне кажется, что моя шапка для шапки информативней и веселее. (Ух ты, каламбурчик! Но если Вас не устраивает моя правка, то можете ее откатить.)

Comment: https://www.culture.ru/materials/76547/prosto-shapka

Comment: @Sharon хотелось бы полного ответа.

Comment: Мне кажется, что ответ очевиден. Это разновидность шапки (род + вид) и пишется через дефис.

Comment: https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkcqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJAoiCiAKA3JlcRIZChfRiNCw0L/QutCwINGD0YjQsNC90LrQsDAB

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ

**Как шапка-ушанка хотела раздельно писаться**

Решила шапка-ушанка писаться раздельно. Шапка — род, ушанка —вид, это **родо-видовые** отношения.

— Да ты что, — уговаривают ее другие шапки, — ты на себя в словарь посмотри.

**ШАПКА-УШАНКА.** Русский орфографический словарь: шапка-ушанка.

**УШАНКА,** -и; мн. род. -нок, дат. -нкам; ж. Разг. Шапка с ушами. Натянуть на лоб ушанку. Шапка-ушанка.

А **родо-видовые** отношения — это совсем другое дело, особая **классификация** растений и животных. Каждый вид получает еще **родовое** имя: ***дерево береза.***

— Вот и я получу: ***шапка ушанка.***

— Так  у родо-видовых названий **два варианта письма**, раздельное и дефисное: дерево береза, береза-дерево. А у тебя что? Шапка ушанка, ушанка-шапка. Дефисное написание "ушанка-шапка" не пропустит словарь. Да и  что оно значит? Что ты шапка, а не **болезнь ушей**?

— Все равно,  — упрямится шапка-ушанка, — есть и другие слова с **раздельным** написанием, например:  *краска серебрянка, газ углерод, нитки мулине, ткань нейлон, леденцы монпансье, суп харчо.*

— Это тематические **названия** промышленных  и кулинарных изделий, иногда их даже в кавычки заключают.

— Все равно хочу в список! **К супу харчо!**

— Там **несогласованное** определение супа.

— А краска серебрянка? Газ углерод?

— **Название**  краски по цвету, **классификация** газообразных веществ по химическому составу. А ты всего-навсего шапка с ушами.

Так и спорят до сих пор шапка-ушанка с остальными шапками…

**P. S.** Но почему все-таки: *шляпа сомбреро, цирк шапито, ресторан бистро, идея фикс.* **Исключения**: *жилетка-болеро, программа-максимум, суп-пюре, театр-варьете, шкаф-купе и др*.?

Здесь **несклоняемость** имеет значение  (несогласованное определение в постпозиции, раздельное написание). В других же случаях явно **определительное**  значение приложения, как и у нашей **шапки-ушанки**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Головных уборов много, они различаются по характерной форме, например: ***шапка, шлем, кепка, фуражка, шляпа***.

Шапка — это вид головного убора. **ШАПКА** 1. Головной убор, преимущественно теплый, мягкий.

**Шапка** — определяемое существительное, **ушанка** — определение/приложение, в постпозиции приложение пишется через дефис. Указываются характерные признаки шапки (ушанка, невидимка). **Все очевидно!**

2. Почему же возникают **сомнения**? К миру вещей не стоит применять родо-видовые отношения по принципу: род — шапка, вид — ушанка, поэтому надо писать раздельно: ***шапка ушанка***, сравнить: ***дерево береза***.

В мире вещей **свои отношения**, своя иерархия: приложение и определяемое существительное.  Для каждого случая собственное решение. Ушанка — частный признак шапки, поэтому это приложение.

3. А почему не стоит, **что за запрет?** Хорошо, попробуем так считать.

(1) Напишем через дефис: ***шапка-ушанка*** (береза-дерево) Здесь **шапка** — вид, а **ушанка** — родовое слово. Звучит странно, хотя запись корректная.

(2) Попробуем  написать: ***ушанка-шапка*** (береза-дерево)  Здесь ушанка — вид,  а шапка — родовое слово. Ушанка — это шапка с ушами, если что, но не болезнь ушей. Тоже странное толкование.

(3) Попробуем написать раздельно:

***Шапка ушанка*** (дерево береза).  Основная информация в видовом слове ушанка,  а шапка только напоминает нам  о том, что это не болезнь ушей.

(4) ***Ушанка шапка*** (дерево береза).   Основная информация в видовом слове шапка, а ушанка общее название **всех головных** уборов (то, что надето **на уши**). Странное толкование.

4. **Вывод.** Лучше и не вспоминать о родо-видовых отношениях, там свои законы. Это особая тема в русском языке, ее можно применить к **ограниченному классу слов.**

Шапка-ушанка к этим словам **не относится**. Задача решается для двух **нарицательных** существительных по принципу: определяемое существительное (основное содержание)  + приложение-определение.  Ушанка — это **шапка с ушами.** Шапка-невидимка, плащ-невидимка  — тот же принцип.

А иначе **простейшая** задача будет казаться **не имеющей** решения. Но это я так думаю. А что **думают другие** участники (**три голоса, классный вопрос!**), пусть они нам  **расскажут**. Интересно было бы послушать.

**P. S.** **Но нет, не рассказали.**  И автору мой ответ **не приглянулся.** Впрочем, как и всем остальным.

Comment: Sharon, с удовольствием поддержу ваш ответ. Непонятно вот это: "К миру вещей не стоит применять родо-видовые отношения, поэтому надо писать раздельно". А самое главное, я запутался в пунктах (1), (2), (3), (4). Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Ну и вот здесь опечатка: "пусть он нам нам расскажут".

Comment: Спасибо, Александр, за интерес к теме. Вчера  я собиралась удалить ответ без голосов и комментариев (просто не успела это сделать), но сейчас решила заменить его (сделаю это чуть позже) более простым и понятным вариантом. Собственно говоря, необязательно было расписывать тему так подробно, но достаточно обозначить общую идею и привести хотя бы один пример. Кстати, для меня так и остается загадкой: почему участники посчитали вопрос классным  и где их ответы по теме.  Я изначально не видела никакой разницы между шапкой-ушанкой и шапкой-невидимкой.

Comment: Но сейчас философия вопроса видится яснее. Мне и в голову не приходило, что можно не различать родо-видовые названия и обычные нарицательные, а для других это обычная практика.

Comment: Видимо, сбивает с толку то, что кроме примеров с животными и растениями (как мне кажется, более понятных) есть и такие: *краска серебрянка, газ углерод, нитки мулине, ткань нейлон, леденцы монпансье, суп харчо* (из Розенталя).

Comment: Да, стоят особнячком эти сочетания. Но мы никогда не скажем серебрянка-краска  и углерод-газ.  Этим сочетаниям кавычки бы не помешали)  краска "серебрянка", а то хорошо замаскировались.  А вы не хотите ответить на вопрос? Может, разрешить написание: шапка ушанка, пусть народ не мучается.

Comment: Нет, я не знаю ответа. В этой теме много исключений.

Comment: Боюсь, что это не исключения, а нечто другое. Названия предметов в разных классификациях.  А для животных и растений классификация общая.  А шапку точно не хотите раздельно писать?  Чем она хуже супа харчо?  Надо Буратино в тему позвать, он в названиях хорошо разбирается, в Болонском университете учился)

Comment: Я отвечал на [вопрос о супе, ресторане и шкафе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472534/О-странностях-русского-языка), но там речь о неизменяемых приложениях, например: *шляпа сомбреро, цирк шапито, ресторан бистро, идея фикс*. Исключения: *жилетка-болеро, программа-максимум, суп-пюре, театр-варьете, шкаф-купе* и др. (хотя они вовсе, на мой взгяд, не исключения) // А писать можно по накопленному опыту, по интуиции, ну и по словарным фиксациям.

Comment: Тем более, вы уже работали с темой.  Так все дело в склоняемости ушанки? Я в таких случаях против опыта и интуиции)  Мне ясность нужна. Язык логичен, а мы должны понимать его логику. и словарные фиксации.